# How to run Jenkins pipeline in a container based on a dockerfile?

Tags: docker, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins

I'm trying to run a pipeline inside a container based on a dockerfile I've stored in my SCM.

Here below the beginning of my pipeline:

```
pipeline {
    agent { 
        dockerfile {
            dir '002_CICD'
        }

    }
....
```

When I try to run the pipeline I have the following error:

```
   + docker build -t 66dae53280bc29614c69b505e48424c25e689b91 -f 002_CICD/Dockerfile 002_CICD
/var/jenkins_home/workspace/AMP_app_docker_pipe@tmp/durable-cbf3977b/script.sh: 1:
 /var/jenkins_home/workspace/AMP_app_docker_pipe@tmp/durable-cbf3977b/script.sh: docker: not found
```

To run the docker container I've installed the following Jenkins plugins:

1. Docker plugin
2. docker-buil-step
3. Docker Pipeline
4. Docker commons plugins
5. Docker API plugin

I've also enabled the docker API on a remote server and the connections looks fine.

What am I missing?
Many thanks

Comment: Check what is the user that runs Jenkins master/worker. I would guess that this user may not have an access to the `docker` client, and you may need to add this user to the `docker` group.

Comment: You are trying docker in docker approach?. By the looks of it you already have docker installed the slave is up using the docker file as reference and once the slave is up you are trying to execute a docker inside container ? AM I RIGHT ?

Comment: Thanks Szymon Stepniak and error404. Maybe some more color on what I'm trying to do can clarify the problem. I'm running a jenkins server inside a container on a remote machine (note that I don't have docker in the same container). I enabled the docker API of this remote machine and, if I have correctly understood, I can use the docker API to execute docker instructions (like the execution of the dockerfile agent of my pipeline). @error404: yes I'm trying a docker in docker approach but the issue comes when I'm trying to built the first container.

Comment: @LucaFiorentino yes..but you need to install docker client not docker engine in order to use the docker API! The docker client will use the docker api of the host i.e the host docker engine for all the operations!

Comment: @error404: Thanks. It was indeed the absence of the docker CLI the problem. I thought that the CLI was installed by one of the previous plugin. Once installed the CLI I moved to a different bug (it seems that Jenkins is looking for the daemon inside the container instead of on the host machine => Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running? )  but at least I moved ahead. Many thanks .

Comment: np @LucaFiorentino I would like to post this as an answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are trying to implement is a docker in docker setup(quite used with regard to the CI process)

As your jenkins is running inside a container you need to install a docker (cli/client) in your Dockerfile hence the error docker not found.

This docker client is will use the docker engine of the host for performing all the operations

With regards to the error

**Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock**

This can occur if the jenkins user doesn't have access to the host /var/run/docker.sock. Check the permissions of this file on host and the associated permissions of the user with which jenkins is running